# Show content when hovering over DIV

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, mousehover

Is it possible to show content when hovering over the DIV. See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4b0G.jpg)

When I hover over the div, the transition takes place, but is it possible to show content inside the hovering div, ie. Images etc

html :

```
<div class="flowingdown">

</div>
```

CSS3 :

```
.flowingdown {
    width:1045px;
    background-image:url(images/vertical_cloth.png);
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border-radius:0 0  55px 55px ;
    transition: height 1s;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s;


}

.flowingdown:hover {
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What transtition taks place. What is the exact question?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assume you have the following markup:

```
<div id="parent">
    Some content
    <div id="hover-content">
        Only show this when hovering parent
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#hover-content {
    display:none;
}
#parent:hover #hover-content {
    display:block;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Not sure how you'd do it with transitions, but you'd have to put the same selector at least.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Bpur/)

Comment: @FarhanAfzal this is a transition version if interested: http://jsfiddle.net/5Bpur/1/

Comment: As an additional note: You can apply any style you wish in this way. The only requirement is that the element you wish to affect is a child (or immediate sibling with the `+` selector) of the element you are hovering.

Answer (score 3):

If, per say, you have this context :

```
<div class="flowingdown">
    <div class="something-inside">
        something-inside
    </div>
    <div class="something-inside-but-hidden">
        something-inside-but-hidden
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.something-inside-but-hidden {display:none}
.flowingdown:hover .something-inside-but-hidden {display:block}
```

Working example [jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/JdvwH/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

But wrap your `.flowingdown` within a div.  Inorder to show the entire content,

```
<div style="width: 200px; height:300px;">
    <div class="flowingdown"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flowingdown {
    width:1045px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/hHUa9Ty.jpg);
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border-radius:0 0 55px 55px;
    transition: height 1s;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s;
}
.flowingdown:hover {
    height:100%; //Inorder to show the entire content within the parent.
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/USGUT/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to hide the bottom half of the background-image, but I just tested this exact code and it worked fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.flowingdown {
    width:1045px;
    background-image:url(../Pictures/C_2560x1400.jpg);
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border-radius:0 0  55px 55px ;
    transition: height 1s;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s;


}

.flowingdown:hover {
    height:100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flowingdown">

</div>

</body>
```

That's the same exact code you used, except I used an image of my own.

If what you want is to change the background image on hover, your CSS should be:

```
.flowingdown:hover {
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(path.jpg);
}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.