# Trying to make text appear over an image when hovering (possibly not using the right properties)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a draft 'Meet the Team' style page for my work and am trying to make the image of each person disappear when you hover over it and text appear that will explain what they do. At the moment, all I'm using is the `hover:` property which doesn't seem to be doing anything. Here's my code below;

```css
.info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #CFCFCF;
}
.info h5 {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}
.info p {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.hoverinfo {
  position: static;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hoverinfo p {
  display: none;
  color: #000000;
}
.hoverinfo:hover p {
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="meet.css">
  <h1>Meet the Team</h1>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="joe" class="info">
    <h5>Joe Bloggs</h5>

    <div id="default" class="image">
      <div id="imagehover" class="hoverinfo">
        <img src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" />
        <p>Test paragraph</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="john" class="info">
    <h5>John Smith</h5>

    <div id="default" class="image">
      <div id="imagehover" class="hoverinfo">
        <img src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" />
        <p>Test paragraph</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="jane" class="info">
    <h5>Jane Doe</h5>

    <div id="default" class="image">
      <div id="imagehover" class="hoverinfo">
        <img src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" />
        <p>Test paragraph</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="joe" class="info">
    <h5>Joe Bloggs</h5>

    <div id="default" class="image">
      <div id="imagehover" class="hoverinfo">
        <img src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" />
        <p>Test paragraph</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="john" class="info">
    <h5>John Smith</h5>

    <div id="default" class="image">
      <div id="imagehover" class="hoverinfo">
        <img src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" />
        <p>Test paragraph</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="jane" class="info">
    <h5>Jane Doe</h5>

    <div id="default" class="image">
      <div id="imagehover" class="hoverinfo">
        <img src="DefaultProfile.png" border="0" />
        <p>Test paragraph</p>

      </div>

    </div>
```

I am a bit of a beginner at this, so I know that I'm probably not using the right thing. Would it make more sense to use the animate property to fade the image out and fade the text in. Also after digging around, some people were mentioning using `jQuery` which I don't have any experience with thus far. Anyway, if anyone could help with what I'm trying to do, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show content when hovering over DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858928/show-content-when-hovering-over-div)

Comment: Position relative on the #imagehover.hoverinfo div, and absolute position on the paragraph.

Comment: @pol Thanks - so create a new property in css for the image and set the position to relative?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to hide the class or ID with display:none and set class/ID:hover to display:block.

To fade the image in or out, you could use opacity instead of display:none; and use a css transition like ease.in/out

**Updated code to keep the Text centered in proportion to the image**

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 320px;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.hoverinfo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #CFCFCF;
  position: relative;
}

.hovertext {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.hoverinfo:hover .hovertext {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
.hoverinfo:hover .hoverimage {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h5 class="headline">Joe Bloggs</h5>
  <div class="hoverinfo">
    <img class="hoverimage" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/300/" />
    <div class="hovertext">Test paragraph</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h5 class="headline">Joe Bloggings</h5>
  <div class="hoverinfo">
    <img class="hoverimage" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/300/" />
    <div class="hovertext">Test paragraph</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h5 class="headline">Joe Bloggers</h5>
  <div class="hoverinfo">
    <img class="hoverimage" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/300/" />
    <div class="hovertext">Test paragraph</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h5 class="headline">Jane Bloggers</h5>
  <div class="hoverinfo">
    <img class="hoverimage" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/300/" />
    <div class="hovertext">Test paragraph</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: -Thanks for your help, but will this just hover the text over the image? Is there a way I can get the image to fade out and the paragraph to fade in when I hover?

Comment: yes of course you could make a css transition, it would fade the image out and fade the text in.

Comment: i added another version with a fade-in / fade-out , i hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it's been a major help. The only thing is, is that when I hover over the image, the text fades in BELOW where the image was, not using the same space as it. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I will modify the code and update it, no worries, you are welcome :) accept the answer if the new code works for you :) .

Comment: It's just a small image, replace it with a bigger one and change. container and .hoverinfo width and height